# Linux high cpu usage - htop shows 90% to 100% cpu usage

Tags: linux, cpu-usage, manjaro, interrupts, htop

I installed a fresh Manjaro Linux on my laptop and it works okay but I noticed high CPU usage when i ran the htop command. One of the cores were constantly busy near 100% and the 2nd one was around 90% (I got 4 cores, the remaining 2 are running normally). The laptop is usable but my battery is draining faster than before.

**I already found a solution** and posting it here to hopefully help someone who is a Linux beginner like myself.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to create a systemd service that disables the problematic interrupt and executes automatically every time the system boots.

First I needed to identify the problematic interrupt by running:

```
$ grep . -r /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/
```

I saw one of them (**/gpe11**) had this big number while all the others had 0.

```
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe11:  7418350  STS disabled     unmasked
```

Then I created a service file:

```
$ cd /etc/systemd/system/
$ sudo touch disableInterrupts.service
$ sudo nano disableInterrupts.service
```

Then i wrote this inside disableInterrupts.service, pasted the path to the interrupt I found.

```
[Unit]
Description=Disables Interrupts

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c 'echo "disable" > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe11'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then I enabled the service so it executes automatically when system is booted.

```
sudo systemctl enable disableInterrupts.service
```

Rebooted the computer and then run the htop again.
CPU usage is normal now.